# Angular typescript concatenating numbers instead of adding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-router

I have three users , when I click on next it has to load route for next user, SO I am adding one to id and passing to routerLink, bu somehow instead of adding it is concatenating the numbers, Below is the code

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute,Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  routeSubscription : Subscription;
  id : number;
  next :  number = 0;
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.routeSubscription =  this.route.params.subscribe((params :Params) =>{
    this.id = params['id'];
    this.next = this.id  + 1;
  });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Html Template for this

```
<p>
  user id : {{ id }}
</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink] = "['/Users', next ]">Next</button>
```

Please Let me know why next is getting concatenated with id

Comment: parse string to number before adding. `this.next = parseInt(this.id)  + 1;`

Comment: I would do `console.log(typeof this.id)` after `this.id = params['id'];` to check if it is still number

Comment: @RahulSharma I have already declared id as number right

Comment: @YashwanthPotu  URL params return string and if you add with the number it changes to string.

Comment: Thanks @RahulSharma Understood used parseInt or unary operator , thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the value of the id as returned by the `params` object in `this.id = params['id'];` is a string value.

The following should fix your problem

```
this.next = +this.id  + 1; // The id is cast to a number with the unary + operator
```

Comment: I didn't know the use of the + operator to cast it to a integer. Nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the problem is that this.id = params['id'] is setting a string to this.id, and then 'this.id  + 1;' is the same as "'1'  + 1";

Try to parse it as integer

```
this.id = parseInt(params['id'], 10);
```

Comment: Why did you add 10 in parseInt , I used something like this this.id = parseInt(params['id']) and it worked

Comment: You can omit the second param as long as 10 is the default value. The second parameter is the radix, in other words, the base (binary, decimal, hexadecimal, etc...) as explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt I'm used to add the 10 in my angular apps because the default lint config from the angular-cli throws an error if it's not informed.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript only does type checking at compile time and this is one of the examples where it fails. The problem is that `Params` is [defined like this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/shared.ts#L25):

```
export type Params = {
  [key: string]: any
};
```

This means that `params['id']` is of type `any` and thus assignable to a field of type `number`, even if it is actually a `string` at runtime.

So, as others have pointed out already, you have to parse the field before assigning it:

```
this.id = parseInt(params['id'])
```